# Is it possible to stop intellisense for .sql files in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2010, intellisense

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 to edit DDL for a MySQL database in a file with a ".sql" extension. The IDE insists on providing red squiggles under perfectly legal MySQL syntax, presumably as it's not legal SQL Server syntax.

Is it possible to disable syntax highlighting for .SQL files?

Or, better still, is MySQL IntelliSense highlighting available?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Visual Studio 2010

`Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> Transact-SQL -> IntelliSense`

Uncheck "Enable IntelliSense".

### Visual Studio 2012 & 2013

`Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> SQL Server Tools -> IntelliSense`

Uncheck "Underline errors"

Note that you have to close then re-open any .sql files you may have open.

Comment: You only have to uncheck "Underline Errors".  You can leave the rest on, if you want.

Comment: In VS2015 I didn't have to re-open the files :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't have VS 2010 in front of me now but it should be something close to

`Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> [Language] -> General -> Statemenent Completion`

Uncheck the checkbox for `Auto List Members`

Comment: Nope, that's where I looked - nothing that I can see - anyone else?

Comment: why test when you can assume.