# Visual Studio 2010 Design SQL automatically creates alias

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and I like to use the Design SQL feature to better visualize my SQL statements. However, it seems to be automatically "helping" me by creating aliases for my tables whether they're needed or not.

For example, when I would like to see a simple query like:

Select txt_Column_Name
From tbl_My_table

It shows up as:

Select tbl_My_table_1.txt_Column_Name
From tbl_My_table as tbl_My_table_1

I often use aliases to help keep conflicts down and make it easier to read the statement. However, this use of automatic aliases make a simple statement unnecessarily complicated.

Can this be turned off somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Try this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8593877/808532):

```
Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> Transact-SQL -> IntelliSense
```

Uncheck "Enable IntelliSense".

Comment: Would that just disable IntelliSense for the SQL editor? I really like it when I'm creating ASP.net code.

Comment: @user2547072 Yes there is an IntelliSense option for each language you have installed in VS.