# Visual Studio configuration for PostgreSQL .sql files

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I'm using VS2013 to edit .sql files intended for *PostgreSQL*. VS thinks they are for *SQL Server*, and spews all sorts of distracting errors and warnings because the syntax is slightly different.

What is the best way to configure VS for editing .sql files that are not intended for SQL Server in general, or for PostgreSQL in particular?

(Preferably without VS plugins, unless there is a *fantastic* stable plugin.)

Can I just disable the SQL Server specific bits somehow? Do I have to associate the .sql files with a plain text editor mode and lose syntax highlighting entirely?

Comment: Found a [similar question about MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4548112/is-it-possible-to-stop-intellisense-for-sql-files-in-visual-studio-2010). I guess that the answer there is a good start here as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Go to Tools -> Options -> Text Editor/SQL Server Tools -> Intellisense and turn Intellisense off. That will make the warnings go away.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into the same problem.  It's rather annoying, but easy to fix.  In Visual Studio, click on one of the problem sql files.  In the properties box for that file, change the "Build Action" to "None".  Viola.

Note: You may then need to close the file for it to take effect.

Edit: Due to downvotes, I suspect this may no longer work.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not seem to work (anymore), so I have used the accepted answer.